# How to increase and reset the font size of html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used following code to increase and reset font size of the HTML.But unable to Increase the font size.I want to increase the font size of the whole body part of HTML page.Following Code i used to increase the font size of the Page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    // Reset Font Size
    var originalFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    //console.log(originalFontSize);

    $(".resetFont").click(function(){
      $('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
    });

    // Increase Font Size
    $(".increaseFont").click(function(){
      var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
      var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
      var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.2;

      $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
      return false;
    });
  });

</script>
```

In HTML page i used following

```
<a href="#" class="resetFont">RESET Font</a>
<a href="#" class="increaseFont">INCREASE FONT</a>
```

Please Help me...

Thanks all in advance

Comment: Your code works for me just fine in Chrome and IE.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ZPdpV/2/. your code is working fine.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/EwHvg/2/

Comment: Based on 'a' tag (substitute to html) in fiddle works fine, you can see the increase and reset.

Comment: Please check this link

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Changing-font-size-of-particular-elements-using-Javascript-1146.php

Comment: Just a note: You should define your font sizes in relative units in CSS and allow the users browser functions to make the text size larger/smaller for better accessibility. Some users may not be able to read/access your controls - best practice is to leave it to their specific browsers default controls. Make the web better for everyone =)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine for me, but if it still isn't working, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/XZfKh/.

```
var originalFontSize;
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Reset Font Size
  originalFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
  //console.log(originalFontSize);

   $(".resetFont").click(function(){
    $('html').css('font-size', originalFontSize);
  });

   // Increase Font Size
  $(".increaseFont").click(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('html').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize, 10);
    var newFontSize = currentFontSizeNum*1.2;
     $('html').css('font-size', newFontSize);
    return false;
  });
});
```

I moved the declaration for `originalFontSize` to the top.

**EDIT:**

If some elements have a `font-size` already specified, use this code:

```
var newFontSize = 100;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".resetFont").click(function(){
    newFontSize = 100;
    var allElems = $('*');
    for(var counter = 0; counter < allElems.length; counter++) {
        $(allElems[counter]).css('font-size', '100%');
    }
  });

  // Increase Font Size
  $(".increaseFont").click(function(){
    newFontSize = newFontSize*1.2;
    var allElems = $('*');
    for(var counter = 0; counter < allElems.length; counter++) {
        $(allElems[counter]).css('font-size', newFontSize + '%');
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

It cycles through all of the elements on the page, and increases the `font-size` for each of them.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/XZfKh/3/)

Comment: @Bharath - I have made some code to work around that, see my updated post.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting font-size only to `<html>`. I guess the issue is, actual text which needs font-size increase, is applied with inline styles or css class which have font-size definition in `pixel`. So that its size is not getting increased. Try setting font-size to actual html element of text or set font-size in `em` for all element in your document exclude `"<html>"`.

Then you can use your javascript to get it work.

Comment: Using Firebug for Firefox, the `<html>` is being successfully styled, with `px`. See the example link in my answer.

Answer (score -2):

I think this depends on your CSS. If you have defined elements below the HTML element (like body, divs, etc) to have absolute font sizes (eg px values) this will not work. If you use relative sizes (eg em's) this script looks like it should work.